# How to open a new email, and assign subject, using .NET Compact Framework

Tags: email, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pocketpc

Basically I'm trying to accomplish the same thing that "mailto:bgates@microsoft.com" does in Internet Explorer Mobile.

But I want to be able to do it from a managed Windows Mobile application. I don't want to send an email pro grammatically in the background.

I want to be able to create the email in Pocket Outlook and then let the user do the rest.

Hopefully that helps you hopefully help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you use C#. You add a reference to System.Diagnostics and then write the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = 
  new ProcessStartInfo("mailto:bla@bla.com?subject=MySubject", "");
Process.Start(psi);
```

This will start the default email client on your mobile device.

The [mailto protocol definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(VS.85).aspx) might come handy too.

Comment: Thanks Petros! Great answer, worked perfectly and was clean and simple, which is something I really wanted and needed. You really helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.MessagingApplication.DisplayComposeForm like so:

```
OutlookSession sess = new OutlookSession();
EmailAccountCollection accounts = sess.EmailAccounts;
//Contains all accounts on the device  
//I'll just choose the first one -- you might want to ask them
MessagingApplication.DisplayComposeForm(accounts[0], 
    "someone@somewhere.com", "The Subject", "The Body");
```

The DisplayComposeForm method has a lot of overloads with options for attachments and more.

Comment: Thanks, Jake, that's exactly what i've been looking for.